# Why the doors color is all the time red even if the doors are unlocked?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

This script and the second one both are attached to the same empty GameObject:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using UnityEngine;

public class DoorsLockManager : MonoBehaviour
{
    public bool lockDoors = false;
    public DoorsManager doorsmanager;

    private Renderer rend;
    private Shader unlitcolor;
    private List<GameObject> DoorShieldFXLocked = new List<GameObject>();

    private void Start()
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < doorsmanager._doors.Count; i++)
        {
            if (lockDoors == true)
            {
                doorsmanager.LockDoor(i);
                ChangeColors(Color.red, Color.green, true);
            }
            else
            {
                doorsmanager.UnlockDoor(i);
                ChangeColors(Color.red, Color.green, false);
            }
        }

        DoorShieldFXLocked = GameObject.FindGameObjectsWithTag("DoorShield").ToList();
    }

    private void Update()
    {

    }

    private void ChangeMaterialSettings()
    {
        unlitcolor = Shader.Find("Unlit/ShieldFX");
        rend.material.shader = unlitcolor;
        //rend.material.SetFloat("_Metallic", 1);
    }

    private void ChangeColors(Color32 lockedColor, Color32 unlockedColor,bool lockState)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < DoorShieldFXLocked.Count; i++)
        {
            rend = DoorShieldFXLocked[i].GetComponent<Renderer>();
            ChangeMaterialSettings();
            if (lockState == true)
            {
                rend.material.color = lockedColor;
            }
            else
            {
                rend.material.color = unlockedColor;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

It does change the lock state of the doors unlock/lock according to the lockDoors variable state in the Start.  But it's never change the doors colors.

When it's unlocked it should be green and locked red. But it's red all the time.

This is a screenshot example of one of the doors:

[image]

Instead spreading around the scripts I moved both top scripts to one:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using UnityEngine;

public class DoorsLockManager : MonoBehaviour
{
    public bool lockDoors = false;

    private Renderer rend;
    private Shader unlitcolor;
    private List<GameObject> DoorShieldFXLocked = new List<GameObject>();
    private List<HoriDoorManager> _doors = new List<HoriDoorManager>();

    private void Start()
    {
        DoorShieldFXLocked = GameObject.FindGameObjectsWithTag("DoorShield").ToList();

        var doors = GameObject.FindGameObjectsWithTag("Door");
        foreach (var door in doors)
        {
            _doors.Add(door.GetComponent<HoriDoorManager>());
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < _doors.Count; i++)
        {
            if (lockDoors == true)
            {
                LockDoor(i);
                ChangeColors(Color.red, Color.green);
            }
            else
            {
                UnlockDoor(i);
                ChangeColors(Color.red, Color.green);
            }
        }
    }

    private void Update()
    {

    }

    private void ChangeMaterialSettings()
    {
        unlitcolor = Shader.Find("Unlit/ShieldFX");
        rend.material.shader = unlitcolor;
        //rend.material.SetFloat("_Metallic", 1);
    }

    private void ChangeColors(Color32 lockedColor, Color32 unlockedColor)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < DoorShieldFXLocked.Count; i++)
        {
            rend = DoorShieldFXLocked[i].GetComponent<Renderer>();
            ChangeMaterialSettings();
            if (lockDoors == true)
            {
                rend.material.color = lockedColor;
            }
            else
            {
                rend.material.color = unlockedColor;
            }
        }
    }

    public void LockDoor(int doorIndex)
    {
        _doors[doorIndex].ChangeLockState(true);
    }
    public void UnlockDoor(int doorIndex)
    {
        _doors[doorIndex].ChangeLockState(false);
    }
}
```

And the script that is attached to each door not changed:

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;

public class HoriDoorManager : MonoBehaviour
{
    private bool doorLockState;
    private List<DoorHori> doors = new List<DoorHori>();

    private void Start()
    {
        if (transform.parent != null)
        {
            Transform parent = transform.parent;
            var children = parent.GetComponentsInChildren<Transform>();

            if(children != null)
            {
                foreach (Transform door in children)
                {
                    if (door.name == "Door_Left" || door.name == "Door_Right")
                        doors.Add(door.GetComponent<DoorHori>());
                }
            }
        }
    }

    void OnTriggerEnter()
    {
        if (doorLockState == false)
        {
            if (doors != null)
            {
               for(int i =0; i < doors.Count; i++)
                {
                    doors[i].OpenDoor();
                }
            }
        }
    }

    public void ChangeLockState(bool lockState)
    {
        doorLockState = lockState;
    }
}
```

But it's still not changing the colors of the doors.

Comment: One bug in my code I found in the first script inside the Start the line: DoorShieldFXLocked = GameObject.FindGameObjectsWithTag("DoorShield").ToList(); should be moved to the top inside the Start. So when it's calling ChangeColors  the variable DoorShieldFXLocked will not be empty. But still it's not coloring the doors in green.

Comment: You shouldn't post all the code, don't make people spend too much time reading tons of code

Comment: The fact that your doors are stored in your `DoorsManager` but the door graphics are stored in `DoorsLockManager` and that Door #1 and DoorRenderer #1 are the same object *by pure coincidence* is going to lead you into trouble. You also pass around some values by parameter (`lockState`) (even though `lockDoors` is class level and holds the same value) and some by class property (`rend`) is a complete nightmare.

Comment: @Draco18s I changed the scripts instead spreading around I did one scripts from the two top in my question. And the script that attached to each door not changed. Still it's not changing colors. Updated it in my question.

Comment: why do you call `ChangeColors` in a `for` loop for each door and within `ChangeColors` iterate over all doors again?

Comment: @derHugo The doors and the shieldfx are not the same objects. The doors are a child of each door and the shieldfx are two doors that are children inside other child of the door parent.

Comment: Look at my screenshot: What I count as a door and List _doors is the Horizontal_Doors_Kit child of each door. And the DoorShieldFXLocked is what I'm changing the color of is child of the Door_Left and Door_Right that make the real open/close. That's why I need to make two loops one over the doors to change the lock state and another loop for changing the colors. There are 13 doors and 24 ShieldFX

Answer (score 0):

This code is working:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using UnityEngine;

public class DoorsLockManager : MonoBehaviour
{
    public bool lockDoors = false;

    private Renderer rend;
    private Shader unlitcolor;
    private List<GameObject> DoorShieldFXLocked = new List<GameObject>();
    private List<HoriDoorManager> _doors = new List<HoriDoorManager>();

    private void Start()
    {
        DoorShieldFXLocked = GameObject.FindGameObjectsWithTag("DoorShield").ToList();
        unlitcolor = Shader.Find("Unlit/ShieldFX");

        var doors = GameObject.FindGameObjectsWithTag("Door");
        foreach (var door in doors)
        {
            _doors.Add(door.GetComponent<HoriDoorManager>());
        }

        ChangeDoorsLockStates();
    }

    private void Update()
    {
        ChangeDoorsLockStates();
    }

    private void ChangeDoorsLockStates()
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < DoorShieldFXLocked.Count; i++)
        {
            if (lockDoors == true)
            {
                ChangeColors(Color.red, Color.green, i);
            }
            else
            {
                ChangeColors(Color.red, Color.green, i);
            }
        }

        for (int x = 0; x < _doors.Count; x++)
        {
            if (lockDoors == true)
            {
                LockDoor(x);
            }
            else
            {
                UnlockDoor(x);
            }
        }
    }

    private void ChangeColors(Color32 lockedColor, Color32 unlockedColor, int index)
    {
        var renderer = DoorShieldFXLocked[index].GetComponent<Renderer>();
        renderer.material.shader = Shader.Find("Unlit/ShieldFX");

        if (lockDoors == true)
        {
            renderer.material.SetColor("_MainColor", lockedColor);
        }
        else
        {
            renderer.material.SetColor("_MainColor", unlockedColor);
        }
    }

    public void LockDoor(int doorIndex)
    {
        _doors[doorIndex].ChangeLockState(true);
    }
    public void UnlockDoor(int doorIndex)
    {
        _doors[doorIndex].ChangeLockState(false);
    }
}
```